# How to create multiple UIViews using the same function

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create multiple UIViews that can be reproduced by using a single function. I have a UIView that is placed on a storyboard and connected to my class with an IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
```

I have a function that loads a xib into my UIView:

```
func createView(layoutConstant: CGFloat) {
        if let customView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TestView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? TestView {
            contentViewTopLayoutConstraint.constant = layoutConstant
            contentView.addSubview(customView)
        }
    }
```

I am now trying to add two of them to my view, but only one shows up:

```
createView(0)
createView(70)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: create separate func and call them multiple times.

Comment: I think you are creating your view in wrong way. Can you try creating it using `if let customView = UINib(nibName: "TestView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? TestView` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both views are added, although they happen to be in the same spot, so it looks like there is only one! A quick and dirty way to verify that would be updating your `createView` method with this line:

```
contentView.frame.origin.y = layoutConstant
```

Basically your `contentViewTopLayoutConstraint` is not connected to the views you are creating, so setting its `constant` value will not have any impact.

Answer (score 0):

Because frames for all those views will of same size. Origin(x,y) will be same for all the views, so they are overlapping one on another and you can only see the top one view.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example it looks like you're only setting a layout constraint on the `contentView` you are placing your two new views inside of. What you need to do is set layout constraints on the two views your are placing inside in relation to their superview i.e. the `contentView`.

Basically, add the layout constraints to the `customView` views.

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple.. iterate a loop by creating uiview along with adding those into the array and customize your particular view by getting them using array index.

Happy code ..